# Data contains missing values after multiple imputation using mice without logged events (i.e., no evidence for constant values or multicollinearity)

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

After the multiple imputation (pmm method) using the mice package, there are still missing values in my dataset (although the number of missing values was reduced).

I have checked that there was no issue with constant value or multicollinearity as there was no logged event. I have included most auxiliary variables in the multiple imputation. I removed 3 auxiliary variables earlier due to the presence of logged events. But after such removal, there were no logged events. I have also checked that no variables/columns were completely empty, whereas there were about 7 participants who did not answer any part of the survey (so about 7 rows were completely empty).

There are 14 variables in the main analyses and 10 auxiliary variables. All of them were included in the multiple imputation. All of them contain missing values. All variables in the main analyses are continuous. For auxiliary variables, 6 are categorical and 4 are continuous. The categorical variables were coded as factors in r.

I wonder why there were still missing values? Is this normal?

Can anyone please advise how can I get a complete imputed dataset? If not, can I proceed to multiple mediation analysis with those missing values?

I used this code for the multiple imputation:

```
alldata4.mi <- mice::mice(alldata4, m = 5, method = 'pmm')
```

Here's the link for part of my datasets: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s_KNTSp4NlxvLYKhVWSPfYbBf0EeniXx/view?usp=drive_link

I've also checked out the following discussion, but they don't seem to have the relevant answer for my situation.
https://github.com/amices/mice/discussions/350
https://github.com/amices/mice/discussions/349
https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1470175-missing-imputed-values-still-present-after-doing%C2%A0multiple-imputation-mice
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330570/mice-does-not-impute-certain-columns-but-also-does-not-give-an-error?noredirect=1&lq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472640/leftover-nas-after-imputing-using-mice

Can anyone please help?